# how to safely discard an unsused variable in OCAML

Tags: ocaml

Here's the part of my code :

```
(* Read the input file *)
let a = input_char inc in
(* Check if a is a number *)
if char_is_number a then
    (* Read the second letter *)
    let b = input_char inc in
    (* Discard the space *)
    input_char inc;
```

Where inc is a `input_channel`. It's reading from a .map file ( by the way, if you have good libraries that I am unaware of that can handle .map file I would gladly take it ) `input_char` will read the next character.

Basically, I'm reading 1 number and a character. The 3rd should be a space ( I will be doing these verification later ) and will be discarded.

My current code raises a warning, saying the last line should be `unit`

Is there a safe/elegant/right way to discard the next character read?

Comment: it works by using the last `input_char inc` into an if statement, but i still wonder if there's a way to just discard a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ignore the return value of an expression, you simply need to use [`ignore`](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html#VALignore) function which serves exactly this purpose.

```
let b = input_char inc in
    ignore(input_char inc);
```

To parse sufficiently complex files, you probably should consider OCamllex +  [Menhir](http://gallium.inria.fr/~fpottier/menhir/), especially if you ever used lex/flex & yacc/bison.

Answer (score 0):

While `ignore` will do what you want, it looks like using the wildcard pattern, `_`, might suit you better in this case, since you're otherwise assigning to "variables".

Consider

```
let b = input_char inc in
let _ = input_char inc in
let c = input_char inc in
...
```

vs

```
let b = input_char inc in
ignore (input_char inc);
let c = input_char inc in
...
```

The wildcard pattern, which you might have come across when using `match`, matches anything and then simply discards the value without binding it to a name. You can use any pattern with the `let <pattern> in <expression>` construct.

Comment: It might be easier to describe `let _ = ...` as binding to the variable _, which can not be used and doesn't give an unused warning.